# Adam Optimizer state in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training a CNN model using Tensorflow on Google collaboratory platform. I am trying to train my model for 100000 iterations. I am using Adam optimizer available in tensorflow which adaptively decays the learning rate internally. Because of either account session termination or some other reason to save time, i am saving model after 1000 iterations and resume the training after reloading my network from the saved checkpoint file.

According to the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#__init__) learning rate is calculated as follows in each iteration(time-step) t.

t <- t + 1
lr_t <- learning_rate * sqrt(1 - beta2^t) / (1 - beta1^t)

My question is when i reload the network from saved checkpoint file then whether optimizer state is restored(i.e variables t,beta2,beta1) from previous iteration (say t = 1000) or it is reinialized assuming t = 0? If it is reinitialized then how can i restore the optimizer state after reloading my model from the checkpoint file so?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/634) the variables are saved. It is unclear if the iteration is preserved though.

Comment: Can you show what you are currently using to train the model? What happens when you run the training process again?

Comment: @McAngus does it means that directly training my model for say 5000 iterations and training in steps of 1000 iterations for 5 times will have similar results?

Comment: @E_net4 during training of 1st 1000 iterations i get constant decrease in loss and increase in precision when i reload the model for next 1000 iterations after 1500 iterations precision shows high variations and drops down to 0 and loss values continues to decrease but after 5000 iterations even loss values does not decrease so i guess my model gets diverged. This can happen possibly because of large learning rate. That is why i doubt reloading the model after each 1000 iterations uses initial higher learning rate(at 0th iteration) rather than using learning rate in previous 1000th iterations.